# How to push every value with its key to $row using array_push using while loop in Php

Tags: php

I have mysql query

```
 $sql="select * from employee where address='Mumbai' ";
```

after this I want to push key and value using array_push by using while loop

```
$row=array();
  while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

                    //code  to  push every value with its key to $row using array_push

                    }
```

How to  push every value with its key to $row using array_push in Php.

Comment: How do you know what the key is?  Also do you really want to use `array_push()` or is that just how you think you can do it?

Comment: @NigelRen I want to pass key and values  to $row

Comment: something like `$row[$key] = $r;` - where you need to set $key with some value (an integer or string value).